# CSS3 flip animation bug in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a flip animation with css3. On webkit browsers the flip looks fine, but in firefox the flip animation doesn't work properly. You can see that the flip animation works, but it looks really "weird" and doesn't flip all the way.

My html:

```html
<li class="employee">
   <div class="employee_container">
        <div class="front flip">
            <img src="http://www.piratealumni.com/s/722/images/editor/headshots/AshleyPerson.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="back flip">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

My CSS:

```css
.employee {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    padding:0.5em;
    height:20em;
}

.employee_container {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -ms-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
}

.back, .front {
    border: 3px solid #cecece;
    position:absolute;
}

.front img {
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}

.front {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:900;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;

    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.active .front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back {
    background-image: url(img/RD.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:90% 93%;
    padding:1em;
    background-color:#ecad40;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:800;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;

    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.active .back {
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}

.back h3 {
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:0.8em;
}

.back p {
    font-size:1em;
    padding-top:1em;
    border-top:1px dashed white;
    margin-top:1em;
}
```

I made a fiddle to show the bug

http://jsfiddle.net/vDQwQ/1/

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** I did a test on 4 different computers(windows and mac OS) running the latest version of firefox, and it's the same on all computer's.

Comment: Firefox is getting confused. :P

Comment: Yeaaaaahhhh, but i wonder why :P

Comment: Lorem Ipsum looks so happy :)

Comment: Did you update Firefox recently? (Currently running 21.0, works fine)

Comment: Yeah im running 21.0. I tested it on 4 different computers(both windows and mac OS) and it's the same bug on all the different computer's in firefox. Compare the animation with a webkit browser and you will see the difference. The difference in the animation is minor but it's definitely bugged in firefox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you declare `rotateY(-180deg)`, the browser has the choice which direction it chooses when flipping the card (the rotation could go from left or from right).

Chrome "accidently" takes the correct direction for both faces, firefox takes the reverse way for the backface. Taking `rotateY(-179deg)` (or `rotateY(181deg)`) will force Firefox to use the same direction.

[fixed Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vDQwQ/12/)

However, the even better way would be to just leave the faces as they are and instead animate the parent! Also you don't need javascript for that (which introduces much less code:[pure css example](http://jsfiddle.net/vDQwQ/14/))!

[This article about 3d transforms](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html) helped me alot when I started getting into the 3d transform stuff. It's definitely worth reading.

Comment: The pure CSS example u just posted is really buggy for me in FF, it get's stuck halfway in the animation

Comment: As of all the bugs, Firefox is always right and Chrome is always wrong :) another day living, another winning for firefox glorified renderer.

Comment: @koningdavid try again with the new version, i fixed the box-sizing problem you introduced with the initial fiddle.

Comment: @Christoph I see you adjusted your pure CSS example, and now it does work for me. Good stuff

Comment: @koningdavid I added a link about 3d transforms, you should have a look - it's great stuff.

Comment: @Christoph Interesting! Thanks alot for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it when you rollover the bottom edge?

If so it is running the *mouseenter* event, then the *mouseleave* event straight after so it never fully animates.

Add the logs to your Javascript for your code in the question

```
$('.employee_container').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    console.log('over');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    console.log('off');
  }
);
```

You may need to add something to not run the *mouseleave* event until the animation is complete.

something like this see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vDQwQ/10/

```
var animating = false;
var callback = function(){ 
  animating = false 
};

$('.employee_container').hover(
  function(){

    if(animating) return;
    animating = true;

    $(this).addClass('active');

    //set small delay
    setTimeout(callback, 100);

  },
  function(){

    if(animating) return;
    animating = true;

    $(this).removeClass('active');

    //set small delay
    setTimeout(callback, 100);
  }
);
```

If you rollover and out a quickly it can get confused.

The best way to prevent anything like this would be to make it work on a click rather than hover.

Hope this helps

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this doesn't solve the issue. The bug is still there. I think the bug is in the CSS.

Comment: I see the new answer above, but if you hover over the bottom edge you still get the issue I found, maybe there were 2 separate issues. Try rolling slowly over the bottom edge in Christoph's fiddle in FF http://jsfiddle.net/vDQwQ/12/

Comment: Oh wow I didn't see that bug untill now! It's indeed not the answer to the question i asked, but you did solve another issue. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Maybe using the method Christoph mentions by animating the parent will fix this problem as you will remove the need to any JavaScript. Probably a better way to go. Less JS is better.

Comment: @koningdavid this problem does solely derive from incorrect box-sizing and can be fixed (together with some other minor glitches) easily (see the pure css solution in my answer) by putting the hover on the parent and including some box-sizing.